# Can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

It doesn't move like it should be and it says:

> x += x_change
>   TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Code is here:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

green = (30,255,50)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("testV1.0")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

CharacterImg = pygame.image.load("Character.png")
def Character(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(CharacterImg,(x,y))

x = (display_width * 0,45)
y = (display_height * 0,8)

x_change = 0

hit = False

while not hit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            hit = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key == K_LEFT:
                    x_change += -50
                if pygame.key == K_RIGHT:
                    x_change += 50

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if pygame.key == K_LEFT:
                    x_change += 50
                if pygame.key == K_RIGHT:
                    x_change += -50

            x += x_change



        print(event)

    gameDisplay.fill(green)
    Character(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Commas create tuples, therefore both x and y are tuples. Use a dot if you want floating point numbers (you also don't need the parentheses):

```
x = display_width * 0.45
y = display_height * 0.8
```

---

Also, in the event loop you have to replace `pygame.key` with `event.key`.

`x += x_change` should probably be in the while loop not in the event loop.

And you have to dedent this block one time:

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key == K_LEFT:
                x_change += -50
            if pygame.key == K_RIGHT:
                x_change += 50

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if pygame.key == K_LEFT:
                x_change += 50
            if pygame.key == K_RIGHT:
                x_change += -50
```

Answer (score 0):

For python, you are using the **wrong decimal separator** `,` in your code, should be `.`

**Bad**

```
x = (display_width * 0,45)
y = (display_height * 0,8)
```

**Good**

```
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
```